# Add proxy to PhantomJSDriver (Selenium C#)

Tags: selenium, proxy, phantomjs

I'd like to listen to traffic generated by phantomjs selenium  driver in c#. The below code does not work unfortunately!

```
PhantomJSOptions phoptions = new PhantomJSOptions();

phoptions.AddAdditionalCapability("proxy", "http://localhost:9999");

driver = new PhantomJSDriver(phoptions);
```

can anyone help me what's wrong with it!

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does it not work? Do you have a proxy sitting at port 9999?

Comment: Yes, I have the proxy at that port .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.HttpProxy = string.Format("127.0.0.1:9999");
var service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.ProxyType = "http";
service.Proxy = proxy.HttpProxy;
IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service);
```

Some quick testing showed this work for me.

Comment: Here's how you add authorization for the proxy:             service.AddArgument(string.Format("--proxy-auth={0}:{1}", "username", "password"));

Comment: @daveL perhaps if you could explain what didn't work, how it didn't work, what errors you get, what code you are using, and post that in a new question you'll get a working solution.

Comment: My bad.. I had a http suffix for the proxy. Doesn't work with that apparently. Works for me now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `CapabilityType` class to set the proxy capability. Here is a modified version of your code above:

```
PhantomJSOptions phoptions = new PhantomJSOptions();

phoptions.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Proxy, "http://localhost:9999");

driver = new PhantomJSDriver(phoptions);
```

This worked for me. Arran's answer did not work for me. For some reason, my `PhantomJSDriverService` class did not have a `ProxyType` or `Proxy` member.