# C#: Headless Browser with Proxy and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, browser, proxy, headless

I am currently using [SimpleBrowser.WebDriver](https://github.com/Teun/SimpleBrowser.WebDriver), a headless browser, for a project.
The browser only needs to be able to run some basic javascript code on a page, I do not want to manipulate the site with jscript or something.

Is there any way to set a proxy for it?
If not, can you recommend another solution for a headless browser with javascript and proxy support?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @L.B: _I am currently using SimpleBrowser.WebDriver[...]Is there any way to set a proxy for it?_

Comment: Pay attention to the **If not** :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhantomJS will help you here: http://phantomjs.org/ 
There is a webdriver for it: http://www.tomdupont.net/2013/08/phantomjs-headless-browser-for-net-webdriver.html

How to setup proxy: [Add proxy to PhantomJSDriver (Selenium C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921099/add-proxy-to-phantomjsdriver-selenium-c)